# How many requests can i send to telegram api

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have a piece of code that i am currently writing, it involves receiving updates from the telegram API and then sending a response to it with python requests module

Right now, I am using a `while True:` loop in a thread to constantly get updates from the `telegram api`. My question is that i am not sure if using a `while True:` loop will result in a `http-requests` time-out or a strain on the telegram's server side. If so I would like to know a better way to handle this. I have tested my bot and it works fine after multiple runs.

I've written this code based off on `python-telegram-bot` package which i assumes uses `threading` and `requests` to get the updates too.

I know the existence of `webhooks` and i am hoping to get a different answer from that.

That being said, does a `post` and a `get` method actually have different strains(likelyhood of me receiving `http-requests` timeout) on the website's server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of strain that a `POST` request puts on the server, relative to a `GET` request, depends on the server and the request - what is it doing, exactly, and how much information are you sending. In general I would expect a `POST` request to consume both more bandwidth and more memory, given it usually involves creating and inserting an object rather than simply fetching a lookup, but that's not a hard-and-fast rule for any API, and there are almost certainly cases where the reverse is true.

The only way you should be getting a timeout in this situation is if the server gets too busy to process your request. Given you're executing this in just one thread, your code shouldn't ever be sending more than one request *at a time*, so I think this is unlikely unless other users are doing the same thing.

That said, you really oughtn't be doing HTTP requests in a `while True` loop with no buffering. Currently (assuming your code is single-threaded), it sends one request, and as soon as it receives an answer it immediately sends another request. While this behavior isn't going to overload the server (it just means that your code almost always has one request sent to the server at any given time), it's way more work for both the server and your computer than it probably needs to be. Probably worse for your computer than for the server, honestly.

*If possible*, you should hook your `messagesender()` method to a behavior of the rest of your program, such that you never send a response unless you actually need to. Failing that, maybe have it activate on a repeating `threading.Timer` at reasonable intervals (4 or 5 times a second, maybe?) rather than using `while True` to run constantly. Or if you can't get any of that to work, `time.sleep()` is always an option, if a clumsy one.

Comment: @Green_Cloak_Guy Thanks for the detailed answer! Just to clarify what you've just said, even if i placed it in a `while True:` it will not overload the server because technically its only sending ONE request at a time? So in what scenario will I be sending multiple requests?

Comment: If you were to run this same code in more than one thread/process (i.e. in parallel on your computer), then you'd end up sending multiple requests at once. Servers do still have a limit on how fast they can process requests, and sending them back-to-back still isn't *good* (if everyone using the server did that, it might actually break it), but it's not going to overload the server's capacity by itself.